# Почему не записывается в файл. PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

$stranica = substr(basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), 0, -4);
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
$date = date("d.F.Y");
$file = ("chetchik/menu".$stranica.".txt");
$file2 = ("chetchik/visitors".$stranica.".txt"); 
$file3 = ("chetchik/date".$stranica.".txt"); 
$file4 = ("chetchik/ip".$stranica.".txt"); 

if(!file_exists($file))
{
    $f1 = fopen($file, "w+");
    fwrite($f1, '1');
    fclose($f1);
    $read = 1;

    $f2 = fopen($file2, "w+");
    fwrite($f2, '1');
    fclose($f2);
    $read2 = 1;

    $f3 = fopen($file3, "w+");
    fwrite($f3, $date);
    fclose($f3);
    $read3 = $date;

    $f4 = fopen($file4, "w+");
    fwrite($f4, $ip."\n");
    fclose($f4);
    $ipkolich = 1;
}

?>
```

Записываются данные только в 2, 3, 4 файлы, а в первый нет — пустой. Почему?

Comment: На этот вопрос вы можете ответить самостоятельно, проверив ошибку после попытки открыть файл.

Comment: Не выдаёт ошибки.

Comment: Покажите как проверяете. В коде даже намёка нет на проверку.

Comment: Может, я не то понимаю под проверкой... только учусь этому языку.

Comment: Ввожу адрес в строку браузера.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать условие `if(!file_exists($file))`

Comment: Не могу, мне нужно это условие, просто я вторую часть убрала, когда пыталась понять, что не так.

Comment: Что значит "не могу"? Попробуйте через "не могу" :). У Вас уже есть/существует пустой файл - вот он и не перезаписывается.

Comment: И правда. Удалила файлы и перезапустила — всё появилось.

Comment: Спасибо большое, хотя проблема была мелкой.

Comment: Логика Вашей последней фразы от меня ускользает. Такая **мелкая** проблема не заслуживает такого **большого** спасиба?

Comment: Нет-нет. К тому, что большое спасибо, потому что сама бы я долго колебалась, пускай и над такой мелкой проблемой.

Comment: @Igor попрошайка! :)

Comment: @Igor Это женская логика, не пытайтесь ее понять, просто примите как есть :)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно попросту права у файла не стоят на запись.
Проверьте пожалуйста права на файл командой `ls -l` через bash и напишите в комментарий ответ. Нету рейтинга на русском стаке отвечать комментами

Comment: Там выше показали, что нужно было просто удалить файлы существующие. Спасибо, что откликнулись.)

Answer (score 1):

Как подметил @Igor в комментариях вы проверяете файл на существование `if(!file_exists($file))` возможно ваш файл существует и не запишется. И как я понимаю если существует `$file` то другие не изменятся, даже если их не существует как я понимаю.